# I would like to use a script to automatically capitalize anything that is entered into a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

ok so im working on a sheet that we use for stock replenishment requests, I have a column that i want to default to capitals whenever any text is entered.  The column  has stock codes being entered into it in the format of XXX.XXX-XX (Capitals and Periods and Dashes)

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1) e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
}
```

It will convert all you type in column A into upper case.

Comment: Its official, Yuri Khristich is a legend!

Thank you so much Yuri, that works a treat, no more messy mixture of upper and lowercase letters...